# I have 3 different functions in c#, that I want to be executed each function after 2 seconds

Tags: c#, .net, timer

Can any one help me how to implement using Time class.

I have 3 different functions in c#, that I want to be executed each function after 2 seconds.

Can any one help me how to implement using Time class.

I have tried below code but it is getting error.

```
Timer updateTimer = new Timer(testt, null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1),TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
```

Answer (score 4):

You have problems (though you've not stated what they are) with calling

```
Timer updateTimer = new Timer(testt, null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1),TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
```

From the arguments you're passing the constructor, I assume you are using [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer) and not [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer). In that case, the [specific constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah1h85ch) that you are calling has a signature

```
public Timer(TimerCallback callback, Object state, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period)
```

I checked and it's valid to specify null for the `state` object, and a negative timespan for `period`, so presumably you have a build error since `testt` does not match the signature for `TimerCallBack`.

Is your error

> [error CS0407](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5141a5y8): 'testt' has the wrong return type

?

For your code to compile, you will need the signature of `testt` to match the signature of [`TimerCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timercallback), i.e.:

```
void testt(object state)
{
    // some code should go here
}
```

otherwise you will get a compilation error.

[Here](http://ideone.com/9SRsdT) is an example of your code which builds.

---

By the way, if you're just going to call `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds`, there is [another constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7) of `Timer` which takes `int` arguments instead of `TimeSpan` arguments - you'd just call

```
Timer updateTimer = new Timer(testt, null, 1, -1);
```

instead. Also, I presume you are setting `period` to -1 milliseconds because the documentation said

> Specify negative one (-1) milliseconds to prevent the timer from starting. Specify zero (0) to start the timer immediately.

In that case, you can make the intention of the `-1` clearer by using [`Timeout.Infinite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite) instead (it's equal to `-1`, but people won't need to know the special meaning of `-1` to see what your intent is:

```
Timer updateTimer = new Timer(testt, null, 1, Timeout.Infinite);
```